# uninitialized constant Ckeditor::PLUGIN_CONTROLLER_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I've try to use ckeditor in my apps. I followed instruction how to install it, but when I came to this step

> $ rails generate ckeditor:base

I got this error message, **uninitialized constant Ckeditor::PLUGIN_CONTROLLER_PATH**, and I didn't know to solve it. Does any body know how to solve it? please.

Comment: Are you sure the ckeditor is Rails3 compatible?

Comment: that's what the page said. (http://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor). They even give us the way how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some issue in your routes.rb If you are using Rails 3... I faced the same and solved it.

If you are using Rails 3 then give

> gem 'ckeditor', :git =>
>   'git://github.com/galetahub/rails-ckeditor.git', :branch => 'rails3'

inside in gem file and run 'bundle install'

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you want to:

gem 'ckeditor', :git => 'https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor'
rails generate ckeditor:install

This works for Rails 3.1